# android Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed

Tags: android, webview

Recently, we've started seeing this new entry in our crashlytics which says that android can't find the webview package on the device.

Here's the full stacktrace  (classes from our source code have been replaced with `....`. :

```
 Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #139: Binary XML file line #139: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #139: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:211)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:20)
       at g.a.a.a.d$a.onCreateView(SourceFile:302)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at g.a.a.a.d.inflate(SourceFile:60)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at ......(SourceFile:148)
       at ......(SourceFile:119)
       at ......(SourceFile:28)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1034)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1182)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(SourceFile:1116)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1642)
       at ....(SourceFile:27)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1320)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:345)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1658)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:1081)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:139)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1485)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7078)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:910)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:712)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:646)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:896)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6369)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1088)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:949)
Caused by android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:395)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:194)
       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2592)
       at android.webkit.WebView.findAddress(WebView.java:1958)
       at android.text.util.Linkify.gatherMapLinks(Linkify.java:599)
       at android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(Linkify.java:287)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4474)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4395)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1472)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:727)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:723)
       at me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView.<init>(SourceFile:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:211)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:20)
       at g.a.a.a.d$a.onCreateView(SourceFile:302)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at g.a.a.a.d.inflate(SourceFile:60)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at ....(SourceFile:148)
       at ....(SourceFile:119)
       at ....(SourceFile:28)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1034)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1182)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(SourceFile:1116)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1642)
       at ....(SourceFile:27)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1320)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:345)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1658)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:1081)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:139)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1485)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7078)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:910)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:712)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:646)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:896)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6369)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1088)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:949)
Caused by android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:294)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:354)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:194)
       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2592)
       at android.webkit.WebView.findAddress(WebView.java:1958)
       at android.text.util.Linkify.gatherMapLinks(Linkify.java:599)
       at android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(Linkify.java:287)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4474)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4395)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1472)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:727)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:723)
       at me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView.<init>(SourceFile:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:211)
       at g.a.a.a.d.a(SourceFile:20)
       at g.a.a.a.d$a.onCreateView(SourceFile:302)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at g.a.a.a.d.inflate(SourceFile:60)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at ....(SourceFile:148)
       at ....(SourceFile:119)
       at ....(SourceFile:28)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1034)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(SourceFile:1182)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(SourceFile:1116)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1642)
       at ....(SourceFile:27)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1320)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:345)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1658)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:1081)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:139)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1485)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7078)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:910)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:712)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:646)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:896)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6369)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1088)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:949)
```

We are seeing this on :

Android versions : 5,6,7

Devices Manufacturers: Lenovo, oneplus, samsung, motorola

And, the devices are not rooted.

After searching for a while, I am not able to find any appropriate cause (and handling) for this. Went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878562/failed-to-load-webview-provider-no-webview-installed) question also but it doesn't have any solution.

Please help.

Edit : This is happening for a lot of our users, so I can't go and tell everyone to check/install webiew from the play store. 
Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: The webview isn't installed. Install it from Google Play ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview))

Comment: Doesn't it come by default ? at least in stock android?

Comment: yeah, but I am not converned only about my device. This crash is happening on a lot of devices of our users and its pain to go and ask each one of them that they should install the webview. I think there ought to be a better solution for this.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue for one of my Cordova app. I have no idea how to reproduce that issue because I do not have those devices that my app users hav

Comment: This issue according to my crashlytics is not restricted to any device group or os group, happening for anyone

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I figured out a probable problem here. As we know that webview has been shipping as a separate app from android 5.0, it may be the case that **at the time my view is being inflated, the webview package is being updated by the os and therefore it can't find the webview pacakge for those few moments**. I know it's a very borderline case but

- as I can see, the crash is happening on only >= 5.0 devices which support this hypothesis
- it's very hard to believe that all such devices don't have webview installed. As a matter of fact, I tried uninstalling the system and chrome packages from my device but still the app doesn't crash.

So here's what I did (hacky solution but prevents crashes):

```
try {
        // the inflating code that's causing the crash 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().contains("webview")) {
            // If the system failed to inflate this view because of the WebView (which could
            // be one of several types of exceptions), it likely means that the system WebView
            // is either not present (unlikely) OR in the process of being updated (also unlikely).
            // It's unlikely but we have been receiving a lot of crashes.
            // In this case, show the user a message and finish the activity
        }
    }
```

Basically nothing but handling that exception. No rocket science there.

Comment: The reason makes sense but I am still surprised Android would have such issue. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, agree with that !

Comment: for my case which using EmojiTextView, the app even not go in catch part and crashes!

Comment: In my case issue happens on "setContentVIew" on onCreate(), what should I do

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.weblayout);
                //View initializations below
         }

Comment: I agree with Author and Shyam Sunder. If your layout has a TextView with parameter android:autoLink="all" ("web", etc.) and text contains some kind of hiperlink, you'll see a crash during inflating the View with exception like: caused by android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview.    Still happens

Comment: My message contains "WebView" not the lowercase "webview"

Comment: if we are using a open source library what is an example of "the inflating code thats causing the crash" would it be where the webview is being intitalized ?

Comment: will it crash just from being declared as a class object above onCreate() or only once were actually using it ?

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce this crash in Android emulator?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue in Android 12. I opened the `Android System Webiew` in my Play Store app and uninstalled it. After it was uninstalled I enabled it by clicking on the Enable button. That worked for me. As pointed out in the comments, this solution is not valid for issue faced by users in production. I faced this during development in a recently updated device.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've had this issue with Android 12 since the first beta and this finally solved the crash on launch of my app, which used react-native-webview. 

Comment: But how will you do that in User's device?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this issue.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78203310)

**Workaround**

```
try {
    super.setText(spannableStringBuilder, type);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // WebView is not installed in some devices by default, Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES causes the exception
    if (e.getMessage().contains("webview")){
        setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
    }
    super.setText(spannableStringBuilder, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My exception is

```
android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException

Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
```

detail stack is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cn.trinea.android.developertools/a.a.aa}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class a.a.ab
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
......
android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException:Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:270)
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:330)
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:194)
android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2325)
android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2320)
 android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2379)
 android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4023)
 android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4146)
 android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
 android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:627)
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:572)
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:555)
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
```

solution is

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    @Override
    public void setOverScrollMode(int mode) {
        try {
            super.setOverScrollMode(mode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().contains("Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed")) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you handling this in a setOverScrollMode() method?

Comment: It is not working on my side

Comment: This doesn't solve the source of the exception; you're just swallowing the exception and preventing your app from crashing. Your webview code will still not work as expected, and this shouldn't be treated as a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the TextView's [sourceCode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r1/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java)

```
if (mAutoLinkMask != 0) {
    ...
    if (Linkify.addLinks(s2, mAutoLinkMask)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The textview with `android:autoLink` property will call `Linkify.addLinks` (reaches the method of `WebView` finally) and cause the crash.

So, we can remove the `android:autoLink` property and realize with other way to fix the problem.

Comment: It's better to put the solution here as an answer instead of an external link.
That would make this a better answer. External links may break which could make this one a low quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I run my app on Android 8.0 Simulator, the exception is:

```
Chromium WebView package does not exist
                 android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
```

And I google `android system webview for android 8`, and download `Android System Webiew` apk from https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/android-system-webview-85-0-4183-101-release/

After `adb install com.google.android.webview_85.0.4183.101-418310153_minAPI21\(arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk`

problem was solved

Comment: Which "simulator" are you using?

Comment: @JustTheHighlights Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exception thrown in Crashlytics. Answer when inflating XML was not working for me because of view binding and it still crashed. So I moved the try/catch to my first activity (splash) and inside onCreate() I put this:

```
try {
    new WebView(this);
}
catch (AndroidRuntimeException e) {
    String msg = e.getMessage();
    if (msg != null && msg.contains("No WebView installed")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install or enable WebView in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```