# React Native - Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed

Tags: android, react-native, webview, onesignal

I'm seeing this error in fabric which is causing a lot of crashes.
I have searched a lot but failed to find anything useful.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048912/android-failed-to-load-webview-provider-no-webview-installed) but I cannot see how it relates to react native.

I'm not using WebView in my code but I thought maybe one of my node_modules packages is using it and the only one that included WebView in it was `react-native-onesignal`

Here is the full stacktrace

[image: Here]

It's only happening in android 7. But it might just be that android put Webview in a seperate package from android 5+

[image: Only on android === 7]

Comment: did you figure out what the issue is ? I am running into same issue, I think using websockets in my project is causing the webview to get involved. Please let me know if you have worked around this issue

Comment: @ak No, unfortunately, I could not figure out the problem.

Comment: thanks  for the reply, so you ended  up abandoning the React Native app approach and went for other alternatives ?

Comment: @ak In my case, the problem was happening to a small number of users, I don't remember quite well but I think it some kind of compatibility issue with the js bundle and the native code.

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

This crash has been fixed in react-native master around April end 2019.
To fix this issue you need to upgrade to react-native version `0.60.0` or above.

Here is the link to the PR that fixed the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/24533

Edit:

To shed more light on this issue, we have been facing the same crash on our app. The most probable reason that I could find was that this crash occurs when the Android System WebView is updating in the background while your app is trying to use it. This causes the system to assume that the WebView is not installed.

This android issue is being tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506369).

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that onesignal is including the webview? The [source](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal) doesn't have a webview except in the proguard rules

My instincts tell me this has nothing to do with onesignal. Hope you were able to resolve