# Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview, inflate-exception

In the project that I am currently working on uses a webview for Login (OAuth). Please find the below stackTace where the activity has not been inflated and has been crashed. The below is the exact exception seen in the firebase crashlytics.

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity
   ComponentInfo{{package}/{classname}}: android.view.InflateException:
   Binary XML file line #14 in {package}:layout/{activity_xml_file}:
   Binary XML file line #14 in {package}:layout/{activity_xml_file}:
   Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
   
   Caused by android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #14 in
   {package}:layout/{activity_xml_file}: Binary XML file line #14 in
   {package}:layout/{activity_xml_file}: Error inflating class
   android.webkit.WebView
   
   Caused by android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #14 in
   {package}:layout/{activity_xml_file}: Error inflating class
   android.webkit.WebView
   
   Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0
   
   Caused by
   android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException Failed
   to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
```

The crash has occurred on setContentView of the activity, when on setting the view to the respective activity.

On looking into other solutions from StackOverFlow, some suggested to use try and catch block on loading the view to the activity setContentView().

Is there any possible way to handle this other than try and catch.

Referred Links :

[android Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048912/android-failed-to-load-webview-provider-no-webview-installed)

Comment: Found any solution?